# Is this a good candidate for a shared (static) class?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, static

I am creating a *caching* class that contains public instances of `Dictionary`. The class serves the entire application, there can only ever be one global instance, and its lifetime is the same as the application itself.

Is this use-case a good candidate for a shared (static) class? I know there are subjective opinions on this but I'm hoping for objective pros/cons if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but:

I would never expose the dictionaries publicly. Hide them behind methods, so you control the access. If the app is multi-threaded you will need to synchronize access, or use ConcurrentDictionary. Dictionary by itself is not thread safe.

If you intend to use this for caching remember that there are already options in .NET for caching. Perhaps your class should just encapsulate one of those ?

In a web context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx
In a non-web context: Perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nice answer. I have wrapped the Dictionary objects as you suggested. Thankfully no multi-threading required. The .NET caching classes you mention look awesome. But MemoryCache is only available from .NET 4 onwards and I'm still targeting version 3.5.